# APEX Replay Debugger truncates String variables

Tags: apex, apex-replay-debugger

APEX Replay Debugger truncates String variables and displays how many "**more**" characters would have been there in parentheses.
How can I get the full String?
None of the options of the Right Click menu allow me to get it, including "Copy Value." It still copies the "**(22 more) ...**" garbage.

[image]

Comment: Actually, the log truncates the string, not the Apex Replay Debugger (I'm pretty sure, anyways). The debugger can't output information it never had. I'm not sure there's a fix for this.

Comment: Upon manual inspection of the log, you're right. I was a fool to think this would be as good as other debuggers. Thanks!